# Unable to access array value based off key?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access a value in the array by passing in the key, but it returns undefined.

```js
 const names = {
      aegon: 'targaryen',
      arya: 'stark',
      cersei: 'lannister'
    }

    let keys = Object.keys(names);

    console.log(keys['aegon'])
```

Comment: please add the expected result as well.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want: `names['aegon']`?

Comment: @NinaScholz the result is supposed to print `targaryen`

Comment: `keys` is an array, so using a property accessor like that does nothing.  `keys[0]` would give you `"aegon"`.

Comment: Along with what @Amy said, in `keys` "aegon" is the value not the key so you can't access it as a key.  That value's index is 0 so you access it as `keys[0]`.

Comment: @JorahFriendzone The expected result should be in the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys() returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable properties found directly upon object. The ordering of the properties is the same as that given by looping over the properties of the object manually. [See Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

I think you are trying to access the value, you could do so with `names.aegon`

```js
const names = {
      aegon: 'targaryen',
      arya: 'stark',
      cersei: 'lannister'
    }

    let keys = Object.keys(names);

    console.log(keys[0]);
    console.log(names.aegon);
```